# Freeze when focus TextField on iPhone 4S on my Codename one app

Tags: codenameone

I'm going crazy with this one.

Since today, my login form worked well.

But now, when I try to open the softkeyboard on taping on the email's textfield my iPhone 4 freeze.

The log shows thousands of line with "We had a signal 11".

Unexpectly I can get focus on the password's textfield !

Both are Textfield components.

I tried with TextArea, same error.

I tried to add/remove constraint, same error.

I didn't have focusListener or others listeners.

Maybe it came from my old iPhone ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This should have been fixed with the update released yesterday. Does it still happen after you run an update project libs?

Comment: Where can I test this version ? I currently use the 5.0 plugin for IntelliJ

Comment: Go to Codename One Settings, Select Basic -> Update Project Libs.

Comment: I got the 5.0 and the bug is still here :(

Comment: The version number for the minor update is in Versions.properties

Comment: Found it :CodenameOne_SRCzip=43
CodenameOneJar=43
CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=12
CLDC11Jar=15
JavaSEJar=43

Comment: OK, can you please file an issue. What's the iOS version on the device?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I face the same issue today in iPhone 5 (32 bit). I installed the app and could navigate some of the screens that don't have a text field. But as soon as I click on the text field on one screen, it freezes the app on the device. Cheers.

Comment: It occurs on ios 9.3 5 13g36 (iPhone 4S)

Answer (score 0):

We found an issue that should be fixed for today's update. This update should be deployed now so new builds would hopefully resolve this.

Comment: I tried today, the bug is still here on : CodenameOne_SRCzip=44
CodenameOneJar=44
CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=12
CLDC11Jar=15
JavaSEJar=44

Comment: I think you should file an issue so we can track this better

Comment: I have filed a new issue #2599 for this
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2599

Comment: Steve made another fix which should be available this Friday https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/390e0206d17fd912d04c1538f7980afa1968d2d9

Comment: Problem fixed ! Congrats :)